# Selecting rows based on Priority -Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a case there I want to select row based Status cloumn Priorty

First Priorty should be Customer_Status with Status 'Deleted'

Second priority should be Family_Status with value 'Deleted'
[ Select top 1 with Family_Status  ='Deleted']

If all Family_Status are "open' then select top 1 Family_Status  ='Open'

Case : 1

```
CustomerID  FamilyId    Name         Customer_Status     Family_Status
-------     --------    ---------   ---------------      -----------
1000         101         Vk           Open               Deleted
1000         102         vk           Open               Open
1000         103         vk           Open               Open
```

In this case i need result as

```
CustomerID  FamilyId    Name         Customer_Status     Family_Status
-------     --------    ---------   ---------------      -----------
1000         101         Vk           Open               Open
```

Case2

```
 
CustomerID   FamilyId    Name         Customer_Status     Family_Status
-------                  ---------    ---------------     ------------
1000          101         Vk           Open               Open
1000          102         vk           Deleted            Open
1000          103         vk           Open               Open
```

In this case i need result as

```
 
CustomerID   FamilyId    Name         Customer_Status     Family_Status
-------                  ---------    ---------------     ------------
1000          102         vk           Deleted            Open
```

Case : 3

```
 
CustomerID   FamilyId    Name         Customer_Status     Family_Status
-------                  ---------    ---------------     ------------
1000          101         Vk           Deleted            Open
1000          102         vk           Deleted            Open
1000          103         vk           Deleted            Open
```

Output :

```
 
CustomerID   FamilyId    Name         Customer_Status     Family_Status
-------                  ---------    ---------------     ------------
1000          101         Vk           Deleted            Open
```

Case :4

```
 
CustomerID   FamilyId    Name         Customer_Status     Family_Status
-------                  ---------    ---------------     ------------
1000          101         Vk           Open               Deleted
1000          102         vk           Open               Deleted
1000          103         vk           Open               Deleted
```

In this case i need result as

```
 
CustomerID   FamilyId    Name         Customer_Status     Family_Status
-------                  ---------    ---------------     ---------
1000          101         Vk           Open               Deleted
```

Can anyone help on this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just order the result set:

```
SELECT TOP (1) *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY Customer_Status, Family_Status DESC
```

Comment: In this how it handles priority with Status 'Deleted'

Comment: When ordering `D` comes before `O` so `Deleted` will be ordered before `Open`.

Comment: There is one change ..i want to show Family_Status as 'Deleted', only if all the rows with Family_Status = 'Deleted'

Comment: That change must go in the question not here

Comment: The `Family_Status` should be ordered in the other way. Descending

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer is helpful, don't forget to accept it